# Iterate through elements of List - Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a List of String, i need to iterate elements and create a new Object for each element in the list and add to a parent list, how do ido in Java 8 , this is what i tried so far:

```
List<CustomObject> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> emailList = fromSomeMethod();
emailList().stream().forEach(email -> parentList.add(new CustomObject(email)));
```

I am getting an error:

"variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final"

Any suggestions ? dont want to do it in the old school way,
Thanks,

Comment: sorry, should have been more specific, i need to either pass email as a parameter to a one arg constructor or i need to have a 2 arg constructor, whose one of the argument will be email, other will be a flag.. can this be done ? i am tring out as we disucs, basically, something like this `email -> parentList.add(new CustomObject(email,false))`

Comment: You can create  2 arg constructor and do like this `List<CustomObject> parentList = emailList.stream().map(s->new CustomObject(s,false)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<CustomObject> parentList = emailList().stream()
             .map(CustomObject::new)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

No need to complicated things, just `map` that and collect to a new `List`

Comment: `emailList` is list of String how this become map to Custom Object?

Comment: @manfromnowhere `CustomObject::new` that is equivalent to `email -> new CustomObject(email)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this You should have Parameterized Constructor

```
            public class CustomObject {
                private String email;
                private boolean isFlag;
            //Getter setter
                public CustomObject(String email, boolean isFlag) {
                    this.email = email;
                    this.isFlag = isFlag;
                }
               public CustomObject(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

            }
List<CustomObject> parentList = emailList.stream().map(CustomObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I see. So the OP tried to add a new requirement instead of fixing the actual problem…

Comment: this worked : List<CustomObject> parentList = map(emailList.stream().map(email-> new CustomObject(email,false).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: yeah if it is only `false` is fine . if you want to send `true`then you must try above (Your comment)way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
static class CustomObject {
    String email;

    public CustomObject(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
private static void test4() {
    List<CustomObject> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> emailList = Arrays.asList("aa@gmail.com", "bb@yahoo.com");
    emailList.stream()
            .map(CustomObject::new)
            .forEach(parentList::add);
}
```